# Hidden field as a (re)CAPTCHA alternative in a ASP.NET MVC2 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, captcha, recaptcha

I am writing a "contact us" form on a web project that I am currently involved with.  While I've used reCAPTCHA in the past, for this project, I would prefer not to clutter the interface with extra images, fields, etc.

How many of you have had experience in adding a hidden field named something like "first_name" to your form.  The idea being that if the field was **not** populated then the submitter would more than likely be human.  But then I ask, wouldn't a bot check if the field was or was not hidden?

Comment: +1 For having user experience in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's entirely feasible. Bots aren't very smart, and they can easily be tricked into filling these fields, some times called "honeypots".

#### Read:

- [Stopping spambots with hashes and honeypots](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html)
- [Negative CAPTCHA](http://damienkatz.net/2007/01/negative_captch.html)

Comment: I'm also having a solution like that. Just go with it, and remember that a solution is never set in stone. If needed you can always change it, but if it suffices it is the best (UX) solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making it a hidden field, couldn't you just hide it with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Though clever, I would not bet all my money on it. Even the more general not-targeting-a-specific-site bots can **easily** be rewritten to skip over fields that are hidden (via css or anything). If hidden fields captcha becomes popular, I'm pretty certain the bots will soon also be modified for this.

This article [here](http://radio.javaranch.com/davo/2008/10/15/1224063498569.html) has some thoughts you might want to consider.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great alternative to Captcha without affecting usability. It might not be 100% secure, but neither is captcha.

It is better to hide the field using CSS than `type=hidden` because bots can very trivially recognize and skip hidden type fields. However, detecting that the field is hidden using CSS would require the bot to parse CSS as well, which while possible, is more work. Bots don't aim to break into every site. They merely look for easy pickings.

Further, name the hidden field something vague such as `foobar` or similar. This is because browsers often autocomplete forms and if you name it something like `first name` there is a good chance browsers will auto fill it.